# Is it possible to determine when the events of Archer take place?

Tags: tv, timeline, archer

Archer seems to take place in an invented timeline:  the internet is commonly used by civilians (which actually began in the mid-90's), the I.R.A. is still active (in the real world, they ceased military actions in the early 00's, and disarmed in 2005), the Russians are still Soviets (which actually formally ceased to be the case at the very end of 1991), Woodhouse is a veteran of WWI (which ended in 1918), Mother was involved in WWII, and so on.  These things probably couldn't happen at the same time.

Or can they?  Is it possible to determine when Archer takes place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [this Rolling Stone article](http://www.rollingstone.com/tv/pictures/how-an-archer-scene-gets-made-20140113):

> [It's] set in a vague, endless Cold-War era," says Neal Holman, a
>   principal designer and art director for Archer. "The vague timeline
>   allows us to cherry pick the stuff we like and ignore the elements
>   that we don't. We can have muscle cars from the Seventies, computers
>   from the Eighties and cellphones from the Nineties..."